# Daywise data and total data

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can you please someone help me to write a query to extract Daywise data and total data from the below query.

```
Select TCl.CircleCode Location,
COUNT(CASE 
 WHEN HostResponse=0 THEN 'Failure' 
 End) Failure,
 Count(Case
 WHEN HostResponse=1 THEN 'Success'
  END) 'Success'
from [dbo].[TBL_DTL_HOST] Host Join [TBL_DTL_CALLACTIVITY_REALTIME_230818] TCL On
Host.CallID = TCL.CallID
Where HostMethod='Caller Validation'
and CallDateTime Between '2018-07-01 00:00:00' and '2018-07-24 23:59:59'
Group by  TCl.CircleCode
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output, and add aliases to your `where` clause.

Comment: Location Failure Success
BLR       2885        64220
CCH 3379 74409
DEL       713               13819
HYD 5077 118209
TCH 7429 134902

Comment: Please update your question with properly formatted sample data and desired output - comments don't allow sufficient formatting.  Remember: *you* know your data; *we* don't.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
   TCl.CircleCode Location
 , Count(CASE
             WHEN HostResponse = 0
             THEN 'Failure'
         END) Failure
 , Count(CASE
             WHEN HostResponse = 1
             THEN 'Success'
         END) 'Success'
 , Cast(CallDateTime AS DATE) CallDate
FROM
   dbo.TBL_DTL_HOST Host
   JOIN TBL_DTL_CALLACTIVITY_REALTIME_230818 TCL ON Host.CallID = TCL.CallID
WHERE HostMethod = 'Caller Validation'
      AND CallDateTime BETWEEN '2018-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-07-24 23:59:59'
GROUP BY
   Cast(CallDateTime AS DATE)
 , TCl.CircleCode;
```

Comment: Code only answers are generally discouraged. It is almost always better to explain what you changed and why that helps the OP.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Joe!  Sean is right - we should probably add comments to our answers to make the solution more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Based on some educated guesses about your data structure and what you mean by "Daywise data", I would suggest just adding a `CallDate` calculated column to the `Select` and `Group By` clauses - something like this:

```
Select
    TCL.CircleCode As Location
    , DateFromParts(Year(CallDateTime), Month(CallDateTime), Day(CallDateTime)) As CallDate
    , Count(Case
                    When HostResponse = 0 Then 'Failure'
                End
            ) As Failure
    , Count(Case
                    When HostResponse = 1 Then 'Success'
                End
            ) As Success
    From    dbo.TBL_DTL_HOST As Host
        Join TBL_DTL_CALLACTIVITY_REALTIME_230818 As TCL
            On Host.CallID = TCL.CallID
    Where
            HostMethod = 'Caller Validation'
    And CallDateTime Between '2018-07-01 00:00:00'
                    And     '2018-07-24 23:59:59'
    Group By 
        DateFromParts(Year(CallDateTime), Month(CallDateTime), Day(CallDateTime))
        , TCL.CircleCode
```

If this doesn't work for you, then you'll need to add sample data and desired output to your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot.This is matching.